# How to persist and access the login Information in all the viewmodels in an Application using PRISM and Unity?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, unity-container, prism

I need to access the login inforation (userid,password(encrypted), and some other information )to my all viewmodel or some  viewmodel. So how can i store these information in common location and can be accessed by all the view models?.

Comment: You can create a single instance of the UserInfo class and pass it to application modules as an interface. Nothing difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Think about a session manager. This manager implements e.g. the ISessionManager interface. This interface is located in your Infrastructure assembly and thus accessible from all modules. When a new session is created via a logon process the session manager gets informed and stores the information belonging to the session. When a view model needs session related information it can resolve an instance of ISessionManager from your IoC container of choice or have an instance injected into your view models.